# Mac OS X - can't kill running process

Tags: macos, launchd

So I've `sudo launchctl unload`ed a particular app that I need to disable for debugging purposes. The system is live and can't be rebooted unless absolutely necessary. So after unloading the launch agent plist, I `kill -9`'d the pid. The process, a user-level launch agent, relaunched immediately under a new pid.

The parent process is my user-level `launchd` which would indicate that `launchd` is relaunching it, however, it doesn't appear in `sudo launchctl list` (it did before I unloaded it).

What, if not `launchd`, could be relaunching this process? I wasn't aware of any other mechanisms besides `launchd` that would cause that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `launchctl unload` (and `launchctl list`) **without** the `sudo`. With `sudo`, `launchctl` talks to the system instance of launchd, which manages system daemons. If you run `launchctl` as a normal user, it talks to the user instance of launchd, which manages user agents.

Comment: Forgot to accept this. It worked of course. :)